# C# Razor syntax

Tags: c#, .net, razor, razor-pages

```html
<div class="field">
    <label class="label">
        Priorirty
    </label>
    <select style="width:100%" asp-for="Priority" class="form-select">
        @if (Model.Priority == "Green")
        {
            <option></option>
            <option selected="selected" style="color: green" value="Green">Green</option>
            <option style="color: orange" value="Amber">Amber</option>
            <option style="color: red" value="Red">Red</option>
        }
        @if (Model.Priority == "Amber")
        {
            <option></option>
            <option style="color: green" value="Green">Green</option>
            <option selected="selected" style="color: orange" value="Amber">Amber</option>
            <option style="color: red" value="Red">Red</option>
        }
        @if (Model.Priority == "Red")
        {
            <option></option>
            <option color: green" value="Green">Green</option>
            <option style="color: orange" value="Amber">Amber</option>
            <option selected="selected" style="color: red" value="Red">Red</option>
        }
        @if (Model.Priority == null)
        {
            <option></option>
            <option style="color: green;" value="Green">Green</option>
            <option style="color: orange;" value="Amber">Amber</option>
            <option style="color: red" value="Red">Red</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

For something like this. Is there a simpler way to do this? I'm quite new to razor syntax

Havent tried anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass an expression to an HTML attribute that evaluates to `false` or `null`, the attribute is not rendered at all.

```
   <select style="width:100%" asp-for="Priority" class="form-select">  
      <option></option>
        <option selected="@(Model.Priority == "Green")" style="color: green" value="Green">Green</option>
        <option selected="@(Model.Priority == "Amber")" style="color: orange" value="Amber">Amber</option>
        <option selected="@(Model.Priority == "Red")" style="color: red" value="Red">Red</option>
    </select>
```

But actually, you shouldn't need to set the `selected` attribute value at all. By assigning a value to `Model.Priority`, the select tag helper will do it for you because you set the `asp-for` attribute to that property.